# Can a space have both a conditional and an unconditional basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

Does there exist a Banach space $X$ which admits both a conditional and an unconditional Schauder Basis? If so, can one find an example in the collection of $\ell^p$ spaces?

My thoughts so far:

- I've been able to convince myself that this is not possible in $\ell^2$, but of course this is a very special case.
- The standard basis in $\ell^p$ is an example of an unconditional basis. So the second qeustion boils down to whether there is also a conditional one.

Also, given the type of question, I think I should mention right away that, no, this is not homework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\ell_2$ indeed has a conditional basis. In fact, in every infinite dimensional Banach space with a basis, there exist a continuum of mutually non-equivalent normalized conditional bases. These facts are contained in *Bases in Banach Spaces I*, Ivan Singer. I imagine these results can be found in Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri as well, but  I'm away from my copy of that to check...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that every infinite dimensional Banach space with a basis has a conditional basis. This is a result of Pelczynski and Singer from 1964. A proof of this can be found in *Topics in Banach Space Theory*, Albiac and Kalton, [page 235](http://books.google.com/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C&pg=PA235&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Specific examples for $c_0$ and $\ell_1$ are easy to find and describe:

For $c_0$, the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n=e_1+\cdots+e_n$ is a conditional basis called the *summing basis*.  In $\ell_1$, the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_1=e_1$ and $x_n=e_{n-1}-e_n$ for $n>1$ forms a conditional basis.

Examples of conditional bases for the other $\ell_p$ spaces are known but are not so easy to find or describe.  The text by Singer mentioned in my comment above furnishes explicit examples, though.  For an example for $p=2$, see also the Albiac and Kalton link in the first paragraph above. Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri's *Classical Banach Spaces I* also contains examples (in particular, they show $\ell_2$ has a conditional basis in Proposition 2.b.11).